# Test to determine if the distribution of a subset of points in a bivariate scatterplot differs from the distribution of remaining points

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics, bivariate, bioinformatics

I'm currently trying to integrate some proteomic and genomic data.  This involves plotting the log2 fold change in mRNA levels against the corresponding log2 fold change in protein levels.  The values for approximately 2000 mRNA/protein pairs are plotted in each scatterplot (grey points) and I've created a script which will highlight the points corresponding to a particular subset which belong to a specific biological pathway or process.  Out of the several dozen scatterplots which I've created two examples are shown below - the subset represented by the red data points clearly cluster in one quadrant while the subset represented by the blue points appear to have the same distribution as the underlying distribution for all points (grey).

My question is what test would be the most appropriate to find whether the distribution of the subset is significantly different from that of the general population?

A chapter on mRNA and protein correlation in the book "Computational and Statistical Methods for Protein Quantification by Mass Spectrometry" suggests that a statistical test exists but merely states "These calculations are, however, not straight forward".

Would I be correct in thinking that the following tests are applicable? - Hotelling's two-sample T-square statistic, two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, and cross-match test

I understand that I would have to correct these results for multiple testing as I have a lot of scatterplots.

[image: Scatterplot with subset of points highlighted]

[image: Scatterplot with subset of points highlighted]